# Kendo UI Grid Checkbox Column Field Not Defined

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I am trying to add a kendo checkbox column. I have done this successfully in another grid. However, when I tried to do the same thing in another grid, I am getting a "IsSimple is undefined" error, where IsSimple is a simple boolean model field.

Model for my kendo data source:

```
     schema: {
                data: function (data) { //specify the array that contains the data
                    console.log("DATA RETURN TEST");
                    console.log(data);
                    return data || [];
                },
                model: {
                    id: "Id",
                    fields: {
                        Id: { editable: false,
                            nullable: false,
                            type: "number"
                        },
                        DesignatorName: { type: "string" },
                        TXFreq: { type: "string" },
                        RXFreq: { type: "string" },
                        IsSpecial: { type: "bool" },
                        IsCommand: { type: "bool" },

                    }
                }
```

Here is my column definition for my kendoGrid.

```
        $("#DesignatorFreqGrid").kendoGrid({
            dataSource: DesignatorDS,

            columns: [

                   { field: "DesignatorName", title: "Frequency", format: "{0:c}", width: "120px" },
                   { field: "TXFreq", editor: TXFreqEditor, title: "TX Frequency", format: "{0:c}", width: "120px" },
                   { field: "RXFreq", editor: TXFreqEditor, title: "RX Frequency", format: "{0:c}", width: "120px" },
                   { field: "IsSpecial", template: '<input type="checkbox" #= IsSpecial ? checked="checked" : "" # disabled="disabled" ></input>', title: "Is Special", format: "{0:c}", width: "120px" },
                   { field: "IsCommand", template: '<input type="checkbox" #= IsCommand ? checked="checked" : "" # disabled="disabled" ></input>', title: "Is Command", format: "{0:c}", width: "120px" },


                { command: ["edit", "destroy"], title: "&nbsp;", width: "250px" }
            ],
            toolbar: ["create"],
            editable: "inline",
            pageable: true

        });
```

Here is my JSON object:

```
"other fields........DesignatorName: "11"
EQUIPMENT: ObjectId: 2
IsCommand: true
IsSpecial: true
RXFreq: "55"
TXFreq: "22"
```

As you can see, IsSpecial is defined. **The binding works when I load data into the grid.** The checkboxes are indeed checked. **But if I try to add a new record with the "Add New Record" button in the grid, I will get the error "Uncaught ReferenceError: IsSpecial is not defined".**

If I change the binding to `this.IsSpecial`, I don't get the error anymore, and can add a new row to my database, but then the binding won't work and the boxes aren't checked when loading the grid,

It seems like it should work, and I do not know where else to look. Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: Can you please post the full grid source code, including the model.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `boolean`, instead of `bool`.

```
IsSpecial: { type: "boolean" },
IsCommand: { type: "boolean" }
```

Comment: This is the sort of annoying thing I've come to expect from Kendo, I'm afraid. They should just make 'bool' work, this is the kind of stuff we spend hours fixing